# How to create large size encrypted file using openssl command

Tags: aix, openssl

During the creation of an encrypted file in AIX, I received this error:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in test.img -out test.img.enc 

test.img: Value too large to be stored in data type
14221428:error:0200107F:system library:fopen:Value too large to be stored in:bss_file.c:356:fopen('test.img','r')
14221428:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:358:
```

test.img File Size is  is 35GB

The same command worked in Linux for 100GB file.

Comment: Is this the openssl that came with AIX, or did you install it separately? It sounds like it was not compiled to handle large files. Knowing the version may help as well: `openssl version`.

Comment: Does it help if you use pipes to prevent `openssl` from knowing anything about the size of the input and output files? Something like `cat test.img | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt | cat >test.img.enc`

Comment: EHLO. Pls show the output from `truss openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in test.img -out test.img.enc `

Comment: Thanks all , YES it is default openssl came with AIX - OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011.

Comment: hi Celada , command suggested by you works . tested on 10GB file....thanks

Comment: Hi KWubbufetowicz , truss output is too big ,  can you tell me which portion will be helpful...

Comment: You might be running into a 2 GiB / 32 bit limitation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746751/fopen-failing-for-binary-file - try on a file that's just over 2GiB and then one that's just under.

Comment: @Celada you ought to make your comment in to an answer.

Comment: @derobert sure thing, done.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error, your copy of `openssl` isn't compiled or linked with large file support. `fopen` probably fails because it tries to discover the size of the file right after opening it and fails.

The trick, then, is to make `openssl` read from a pipe and write to a pipe. Pipes have no size, and `fopen` knows this, so it should be fine with it. The things at the other ends of the pipes don't need to do anything fancy, they just need to be passthrough filters between `openssl` and the actual files. That's exactly what `cat`'s job is. `cat`, which now becomes the thing directly exposed to the large file, needs to have large file support, but as an OS-supplied basic utility, let's assume that it does.

```
cat test.img | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt | cat >test.img.enc
```